# How to test wifi adapter?

Tags: wi-fi, sony-xperia, troubleshooting, sony-xperia-z2

My VPN keeps disconnecting and I'm wondering if it's a problem with the wireless adapter. Is there a way I can test? I'm using the Xperia Z2 and there's ways to test the built in hardware like the microphone but not for the wifi adapter. Is there an app like StabilityTest that works on wifi?

Comment: Try the service code `*#*#7378423#*#*` -> Testing ->WLAN.

Did you enable stamina mode? This may also cause the wifi to disconnect

Comment: Thanks. No stamina is not enabled. Testing WLAN didn't really say much, it just asked me a website to enter than said it could connect. Maybe it would be more helpful for me to run a broadband speed test from the phone.